# Force Windows Server to wait for ASP.NET asynchronous threads to finish up on reboot

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis

I've managed to make IIS wait for background threads to finish up in case of a **recycle** or **application pool shutdown**. See code below. This has solved half my issue.

This does not seem to work at all with a **Windows Server reboot**, sadly. It gives our threads 30 seconds, but after that it kills the worker process.

Is there a way to prevent shutdown until our all background threads are finished?

A regular process can postpone a shutdown on Windows, so it must be possible. Perhaps IIS/ASP.NET is standing in our way.

*We are aware ASP.NET is not the best framework to have background threads. We are also aware we can fix this by doing an iisreset before restarting, but it's not always within our power how the server is restarted.*

```
public class BackgroundRunner : IRegisteredObject
{
    public BackgroundRunner()
    {
        // Solution 1: IRegisteredObject
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

        // Solution 2: event gets triggered one second earlier than with Method 1
        typeof(HostingEnvironment).GetEvent("StopListening").AddEventHandler(null, new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            FinishUp();
        }));
    }

    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        FinishUp();
        HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"We are aware ASP.NET is not the best framework to have background threads."* <== Then why are you doing it? Btw I assume that you have already read this: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Sadly this was a design choice by predecessors that I am stuck with for the moment. Long-term solution is to move it outside of the application which will be a lot of work, but we need a short-term solution as well - hence my question.

For anyone else reading this. I came to the conclusion that with a Windows reboot the maximum time-out is 30 seconds, and I can't find a way around it.

I may just write a little Windows service that blocks the reboot until all IIS worker processes are shut down. Shouldn't be much work.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately I can't think of any advice about a short-term solution to the problem.